# What are the range of values of the negativity in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

The negativity of a quantum state, given by

$N(\rho)=\frac{||\rho^{\Gamma_A}||-1}{2}$

where $\rho^{\Gamma_A}$ is the partial transpose with respect to subsystem $A$ of the density matrix of a quantum state and $||.||$ is the trace norm. The measures the degree of entanglement between quantum states. I can plot this for a given quantum state but would like to check my answer is correct. I can't find anywhere what the maximum and minimum values of the negativity can be, and which refers to maximum entanglement. Does anyone have this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Negativity is an LOCC monotone.  Thus, it must be maximal on the maximally entangled state.  It should be a straightforward exercise to compute this value.

On the other hand, negativity is zero on separable states.  For the same reason, this is the lowest value.  (More directly, the partial transpose is trace preserving, so the eigenvalues of $\rho^{\Gamma_A}$ add up to $1$.  Thus, the sum of their absolute values must be $\ge 1$.)

Comment: So a Bell state will have a negativity of 1?

Comment: @JJH I just got 1/2, which I found a bit puzzling ...  but it seems to be correct.

Comment: @JJH ... which is since the Negativity is defined such as to be "the absolute value of the sum of
negative eigenvalues of $\rho^{\Gamma_A}" (Vidal+Werner, https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0102117).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm getting values between 1/2 and -1/2, where 1/2 is a Bell state. Do you think this is correct or should the values definitely have to be positive? I'm using an exponential decay in my model and without this decay all values were positive.

Comment: @JJH The minimum is zero.  For qubits, the maximum is 1/2.

Comment: Ok I can see that this wouldn't go below 0 for qubits without any decoherence but I'm now trying to add in an exponential decay and am getting some negative results. Do you think this makes any sense?

Comment: I have now redone this using the eigenvalue definition and I have the correct answer.

Comment: @JJH How else would you do it, if not using the eigenvalues?

Comment: Well before I was using the tracenorm definition which I realise is basically the same, but I was putting this through mathematica explicitly and I think the problem may have been in the MatrixPower step.

Comment: I know I came late to the party, but I do not fully agree. The negativity of a Bell state is 1/2 as @NorbertSchuch correctly calculated. However, Fig 2. of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.11727.pdf  shows that it can be larger (top right blue point). The negativity in this paper was defined as $E_N = \log ||\rho^{T_B}||$, or in terms of the negativity defined here $\mathcal{N} = \frac{\exp(E_N)-1}{2}$. What we see in the figure is $E_N/L \sim 0.3$ at $L=12$ thus  $\mathcal{N} = \frac{\exp(0.3*12)-1}{2} \sim 17.8$.

Comment: I guess the point I'm trying to make is that negativity depends on the size of the system. Remember that logarithmic negativity is additive on tensor product: $E_N(\rho \otimes \sigma) = E_N(\rho) + E_N(\sigma)$, so I guess the question/answer should reflect this subtlety.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian Welcome to the party! Where in my answer do you find anything which is in contradiction to what you say?

Comment: Thanks! In the: *For qubits, the maximum is 1/2.* It could be simple terminology, but when I hear qubits I am not necessarily think of a particular dimension.

Comment: Sure. That's for a 2-qubit state.

Comment: I am confused now... The negativity of any general GHZ state is 1/2 and by tha above, this should be wrong as it is a maximally entangled state right?

Comment: Negativity measures entanglement of *bipartite* states. A bipartite state is maximally entangled if all Schmidt coefficients are the same and it has maximal Schmidt rank.